# Kafka Avro Serializer: org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: not open

Tags: java, scala, apache-kafka, avro, kafka-producer-api

I am using Apache Kafka with Avro Serializer, using specific format. I am trying to create my own custom class and used as a kafka message value. But when i am trying to send the message i am getting following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: not open
    at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter.assertOpen(DataFileWriter.java:82)
    at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter.append(DataFileWriter.java:287)
    at com.harmeetsingh13.java.producers.avroserializer.AvroProducer.main(AvroProducer.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

My Avro Schema file as below:

```
{
    "namespace": "customer.avro",
    "type": "record",
    "name": "Customer",
    "fields": [{
        "name": "id",
        "type": "int"
    }, {
        "name": "name",
        "type": "string"
    }]
}
```

Customer Class:

```
public class Customer {
    public int id;
    public String name;

    public Customer() {
    }

    public Customer(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Data Serialization using Avro:

```
public static void fireAndForget(ProducerRecord<String, DataFileWriter> record) {
        kafkaProducer.send(record);
    }

Customer customer1 = new Customer(1001, "James");

Parser parser = new Parser();
Schema schema = parser.parse(AvroProducer.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("customer.avro"));

SpecificDatumWriter<Customer> writer = new SpecificDatumWriter<>(schema);
DataFileWriter<Customer> dataFileWriter = new DataFileWriter<>(writer);
dataFileWriter.append(customer1);
dataFileWriter.close();

ProducerRecord<String, DataFileWriter> record1 = new ProducerRecord<>("CustomerCountry",
        "Customer One", dataFileWriter
);
fireAndForget(record1);
```

I want to use `SpecificDatumWriter` writer instead of generic one. What is this error related with ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka receives a key value pair to serialize, you're passing it a `DataFileWriter` which isn't the value you want to serialize, that's not going to work.

What you need to do is create a byte array with the serialized avro via a `BinaryEncoder` and `ByteArrayOutputStream`, and then pass it to the `ProducerRecord<String, byte[]>`:

```
SpecificDatumWriter<Customer> writer = new SpecificDatumWriter<>(schema);
ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

try {
  BinaryEncoder encoder = EncoderFactory.get().binaryEncoder(os, null);
  writer.write(customer1, encoder);
  e.flush();

  byte[] avroBytes = os.toByteArray();
  ProducerRecord<String, byte[]> record1 = 
    new ProducerRecord<>("CustomerCountry", "Customer One", avroBytes); 

  kafkaProducer.send(record1);
} finally {
  os.close();
}
```

Comment: Hey @Yuval, according to this solution, I am getting `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.harmeetsingh13.java.producers.avroserializer.Customer cannot be cast to org.apache.avro.generic.IndexedRecord` Exception

Comment: @HarmeetSinghTaara Well, that's another problem, I suggest you post a different question which includes the definition of `Customer` and the full stacktrace. It seems like you're not implementing the `ISpecificRecord` interface which is required for types you want to serialize. Otherwise, you can use `GenericDatumWriter` instead.

Comment: Okay @Yuval, But according to this solution, we need to convert our data into bytes and after that, we send the message to kafka, is it not possible for specify our schema to avro and avro automatically handles all ?

Comment: @HarmeetSinghTaara No, that's not how the Avro serializer for Java works unfortunately.

Comment: This seems to be complex, like have many models and every model have different structure, then we need to convert all models into bytes and write that bytes into queue.

Comment: @HarmeetSinghTaara I agree, the Java API for Avro is *far* from being convenient. You can consider using the `GenericDatumWriter` instead which doesn't require you to do that. Alternatively (not sure if that's a possibility at all), Scala has a nice library called `avro4s` which reflects over the class structure for you without needing to manually write it out.

Comment: Hey @Yuval, this is working fine, I am resolve `IndexedRecord` issue also.

Comment: @HarmeetSinghTaara How did you end up resolving it?

Comment: I am using https://github.com/sbt/sbt-avro plugin for generate source code of our schema. Because there are lots of things require in pojo class.

Comment: @HarmeetSinghTaara Cool.